microk8s: kubernetes-dashboard and ingress - Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server
I got a microk8s v1.28.14 cluster and I want to use the kubernetes-dashboard.
I enabled the dashboard via microk8s enable dashboard, dashboard pod and service are created in the 'kube-system'-namespace, curl -k https://10.152.183.43 on the service works.
Now I want to  be able to externally access my dashboard. Using cloudflare for my domain with HTTPS redirection and flexible TLS settings.
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  rules:
  - host: cluster.my-domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: kubernetes-dashboard
            port:
              number: 443

The ingress itself looks fine:
Name:             kubernetes-dashboard
Labels:           <none>
Namespace:        kube-system
Address:          127.0.0.1
Ingress Class:    public
Default backend:  <default>
Rules:
  Host                Path  Backends
  ----                ----  --------
  cluster.my-domain.com
                      /   kubernetes-dashboard:443 (10.1.206.212:8443)
Annotations:          <none>
Events:               <none>

When now trying to access my dashboard (`curl -k https://cluster.my-domain.com'), I get the following error:
Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server
Any idea how this could be solved?

AS per this Github issue
The error you are facing is due to the mismatch between the ingress controller and the service routing.
By default the Microk8s enable dashboard  command exposes the dashboard service on port 80. You need to configure it to use HTTPS.
Once the dashboard service is exposed on HTTPS. Make sure CloudFlare settings have HTTPS everywhere. If you are using flexible TLS settings in Cloudflare verify the certificate validation is set to Full (strict)
When you set your encryption mode to Full (strict), Cloudflare does everything in Full mode but also enforces more stringent requirements for origin certificates.
After applying changes restart the pods and services to ensure the new configuration.
See this  similar Article  by  portainer.io and Kubernetes discussion forum   for more  information.

Refer to this similar error stack link for more information.
